# Parsing data from array element of mongoose object yielding undefined whereas simple element values are returning correctly

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have written a query to fetch data into *outVar* variable from mongo db via mongoose object and when i print *outVar* onto console from my js file, i am getting the below data

```
{ _id: 5c24fad96fe8c607b7e73814,
  title: 'Movies and TV series database',
  version: '1.0',
  shows:
   [ { name: 'CSI', genre: 'Sci', lead_actor: 'William Petersen' } ] }
```

*`console.log(outVar.title)`* and *`console.log(outVar.version)`* yields the results *Movies and TV series database* and *1.0* respectively. However, when i try  to print `outVar.shows`, i get undefined.

Please help me in understanding where i am going wrong and how i can rectify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The mongo response should first be stringified and and then be parsed into JSON object. The resulting JSON object should then be used in the following operations, as shown below

```
var outString=JSON.stringify(out[0]);
var outStringJson=JSON.parse(outString);
console.log(outStringJson.shows);
console.log(outStringJson.shows[0]);
```